# Delete records if no data exists after colon using sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have data in below format in a file

```
id : 315,abcid                 :,abcname                 :,abcrole                :,abctest                :,abcsts : Active,abcqwe                :
id : 316,abcid :1234 ,abcname : Test,abcrole : No,abctest : 2345,abcsts : Active,abcqwe                :
```

I am trying to get all fields which has data after : in the below format :--

```
id : 315,abcsts : Active ,
id : 316,abcid :1234 ,abcname : Test,abcrole : No,abctest : 2345,abcsts : Active,
```

I tried using sed to but it deleting whole records.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Comment: What sed expression did you try?

Comment: What does "data after :" mean? Why is `:,abcname` not data?

Comment: When I say data it means something should be present between : and ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/(,|^)\S+\s*:(?=,|$)//g' file
```

The `(?=...)` is a look-ahead assertion, i.e. it checks that the following character is a comma or end of line, but doesn't remove it and doesn't advance the position for the next search.

The output is different to the one you specified: it also removes the final commas.

Answer (score 4):

Short **`sed`** solution - removing *invalid* fields:

```
sed -E 's/[^:, ]* *:( *,|$)//g' file
```

- `[^:, ]*` - matches a *field name* which should be presented with any character except `:`, `,` and a whitespace
- `' *'` - field name can be followed with optional whitespace(s)
- `:` - matches `:` as a separator between *field name* and *field value*
- `( *,|$)` - regex alternation group, matches either *empty* field value (may be presented with optional whitespace(s) `' *'`) followed by `,` (as a separator between key/value pairs) OR the end of the string `$`

---

The output:

```
id : 315,abcsts : Active,
id : 316,abcid :1234 ,abcname : Test,abcrole : No,abctest : 2345,abcsts : Active,
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, better with awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=",|\n";ORS=",";FS=":";OFS=FS}$2!="";RT=="\n"{printf "\n"}' file1
id : 315,abcsts : Active,
id : 316,abcid :1234 ,abcname : Test,abcrole : No,abctest : 2345,abcsts : Active,
```

`RS`  : Input Record Separator (comma or new line)
`ORS` : Output Record Separator
`FS`  : Field Separator
`OFS` : Output Field Separator
`$2`  : Second field as separated using FS as delimiter
`RT`  : Record separator value in use (comma or new line)

My solution is based on adjusting awk `RS` and `FS` values. 
You can get some nice results on your data with a basic awk snippet like this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=",|\n";FS=":";OFS=FS}$1=$1'  file1
id : 315
abcid                 :
abcname                 :
abcrole                :
abctest                :
abcsts : Active
abcqwe                :
id : 316
abcid :1234 
abcname : Test
abcrole : No
abctest : 2345
abcsts : Active
abcqwe
```

The whole line is split using comma.
Each generated lines contains fields of the format
`property : value`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/,[^,]+\s*:(,|$)/\1/;ta' file
```

Iteratively replace a comma followed by a word (not containing a comma) followed by one or more spaces followed by a colon followed by a comma or the end of the line by a comma or the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following `sed` command:

```
sed 's/[[:alnum:]]*\s*:\s*[,]\s*//g; s/,[[:alnum:]]*\s*:$/,/g' input_active.in
```

**tested:**

[image]